# How to create a function that can operate over multiple objects of the same class, accessing private attributes in C++?

Tags: c++, function, class, object, methods

Let's say I have a class C, with some private attributes, for example the integer j. In the main I create two object of that class, let's say A and B. I need to operate (maybe using a function) over one of the private attributes of those objects. For example the task can be to write in A.j the value 2*(B.j). I can't simply implement a write method and a read method, because it's a much more complicate MPI related problem. Is it possible to implement a function that receives in input two objects and "do some job" over their private attributes? I have to declare it among the other methods of the class?
Thank you.

Comment: Please show some example code of what you are trying.

Comment: You cannot access a private member from outside a class, this is the point of private members.

Comment: @Malloc you can, just not directly like a member function returning a reference to the private data.  or via [some other magic](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2011/12/access-to-private-members-safer.html)

Comment: Sibling objects are open books to each other. Private, protected, and public issues are inheritance issues.

Comment: Definition: 'sibling' objects.  Two instances of the same class.  Sibling's can access any attribute (data or method) of the other instance, provided a pointer to that instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `friend` function to access `private` and `protected` class members.

```
class C {
    int j;
    friend void f(C& a, const C& b);
};
void f(C& a, const C& b) {
    a.j = 2*b.j;
}
```

Yes, you have to declare the friend in the class definition.

However, depending on what specifically you are trying to do, this may not be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just implement `get` and `set` methods? That would be the simplest solution...

```
class A{
   int j;
public:
   int getJ(){return j;};
   void setJ(int j2){j=j2;};
};

int main(){
   A B,C;
   C.setJ(B.getJ()*2);
   return 0;
}
```

Or by reference:

```
class A{
   int j;
public:
   int& access(){return j;};
};

int main(){
   A B,C;
   C.access() = B.access()*2;
   return 0;
}
```

Or use a **friend** function:

```
void doSomething(A &a, A &b){b.j = a.j*2;};

class A{
   int j;
   friend doSomething(A &a, A &b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I do not know what you are trying to do, I do not know whether the following solution makes sense in your case. You might try something like the "command pattern", passing a functional telling how the new value of j is calculated from the other object's j (if the syntax looks strange to you, google for "lambda function"):

```
class MyClass {
   private:
      int j;
   public:
      void ModifyBasedOnOtherObject (
         const MyClass & other,
         const std::function<int (int)> & f
      ) {
         this->j = f (other.j);
      }
};

// ...
a.ModifyBasedOnOtherObject (b, [] (int i) { return 2 * i; });
```